# Get month in mm format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

How do I retrieve the month from the current date in `mm` format?  (i.e. "05")

This is my current code:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
if (currentMonth < 10) { currentMonth = '0' + currentMonth; }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I originally had `if(currentMonth < 9) { currentMonth = "0" + currentMonth; }` and it did not work.  Guess I need single quotes instead of double.

Comment: Odd.. the type of quote shouldn't matter! Maybe an artifact of type coercion and the `+` operator ..

Comment: You want `< 10` else 9 wont return '09'

Comment: @Matt: a minor thing, sure, but now you have an int if it's november or december, and a string in all other cases. this could lead to some unexpected behavior upon further concatenation (if the other concatenated value is numeric, say). i'd `toString` in an `else`.

Comment: @David Hedlund - I would agree, but it's not possible to have a leading 0 without it being a string.

Comment: @Matt: yes, that's why I'm suggesting that you do `toString` in the else, so that 10, 11, and 12 (can't believe i missed october in my last comment) are also strings, even though they don't have a leading 0. Gert G's solution is another way of achieving the same effect.

Answer (score 57):

An alternative way:

```
var currentMonth=('0'+(currentDate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)
```

Answer (score 6):

One line solution:

```
var currentMonth = (currentDate.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentDate.getMonth();
```

Answer (score 3):

for the date:

```
("0" + this.getDate()).slice(-2)
```

and similar for the month:

```
("0" + (this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
```

Answer (score 2):

**ES6 version**, inpired by Gert Grenander

```
let date = new Date();
let month = date.getMonth()+1;
month = `0${month}`.slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
```

then currentMonth is a number, which you can format as you want, see this question that will help you with formatting: [How can I format an integer to a specific length in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127905/how-can-i-format-an-integer-to-a-specific-length-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the accepted answer to return a string consistently, it should be:

```
if(currentMonth < 10) {
    currentMonth = '0' + currentMonth;
} else {
    currentMonth = '' + currentMonth;
}
```

Or:

```
currentMonth = (currentMonth < 10 ? '0' : '') + currentMonth;
```

Just for funsies, here's a version without a conditional:

```
currentMonth = ('0' + currentMonth).slice(-2);
```

Edit: switched to `slice`, per Gert G's answer, credit where credit is due; `substr` works too, I didn't realize it accepts a negative `start` argument

Answer (score 0):

```
var CurrentDate = new Date();
    CurrentDate.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth());

    var day = CurrentDate.getDate();
    var monthIndex = CurrentDate.getMonth()+1;
    if(monthIndex<10){
        monthIndex=('0'+monthIndex);
    }
    var year = CurrentDate.getFullYear();

    alert(monthIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative with ES6 template strings**

A solution for `mm/yyyy`. Not quite the question, but I guess remove the second part.

```js
const MonthYear = `${dateObj.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' : '' }${dateObj.getMonth()+1}/${dateObj.getFullYear()}`
```

```js
const Month = `${dateObj.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' : '' }${dateObj.getMonth()+1}`
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer here referenced one on [number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49677621/8616470) but without a code example. This is a general string padding problem that has been simplified since ES2017. You can use [String.prototype.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [String.prototype.padEnd](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) to make sure that a string is of a fixed minimum length.

The return of [Date.prototype.getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is a number from 0 (January) to 11 (December). To be represented as strings from '01' to '12' you might do:

```js
let date = new Date()
let month = date.getMonth() + 1
let display = month.toString().padStart(2, '0')
console.log(display) // one of "01", "02", ..., "09", "10", "11", "12"
```

This similarly applies to the return of [Date.prototype.getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate), a number from 1 to 31:

```js
console.log(
  new Date().getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
) // one of "01", "02", ..., "31"
```

Or simply any value that you want to be a string with a minimum length:

```js
let greeting = 'world'.padStart(17, 'hello ')
console.log(greeting) // "hello hello world"
```